# "no such file or directory" using h5py.File?

Tags: python, h5py

I am running up against an issue where I keep getting the error message

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '/n/home01/user/folder​/subfolder1/file1.hdf5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

when I try to use

```
f = h5py.File('/n/home01/user/folder​/subfolder1/file1.hdf5','r')
```

I am not using the relative path, I am using the absolute path, and I have double- and triple-checked the path is right. The file is definitely in that path, my program just can't seem to access it.

It's confusing because literally 10 lines earlier, I do the exact same call with a different file:

```
f = h5py.File('/n/home01/user/folder/subfolder0/file0.hdf5,'r')
```

What's going on? And how can I make this work?

Comment: Please post your code as well as the full error trace

Comment: Try this code `import os; print(os.listdir('/the/directory/path'))` to see a list of what files are in the directory.

Comment: The path in the error message doesn't match the path in the code you posted (`subfolder` vs. `subfolder1`).

Comment: @JohnGordon done and I got exactly what I expected, I've already gone through that with the command line anyways. Still doesn't explain

Comment: @jasonharper whoops, I renamed stuff because i wanted to make stuff clearer, but clearly failed lol. fixing now

Comment: Try 'ls /n/home01/user/folder​/subfolder1/file1.hdf5' to see if it really exists (copy-paste from the error message), there could be a small detail in the name that's wrong